# Model.where() with multiple params with check if they are present in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Rails. I started working on a POC.

My controller code is below:

```rb
  @xyz = if params[:id].present?
           if params[:mobile_number].present?
             Seeker.where("id = ? and mobile_number = ?" , params[:id], params[:mobile_number])                    
           else                    
             Seeker.where("id = ?", params[:id])
           end
         elsif params[:seekerid].present?
           Seeker.where("mobile_number = ?" , params[:mobile_number])
         else
           Seeker.where(nil);
         end
```

But I don't think it's a good approach. Consider if I have many parameter then putting `present?` condition then forming query would become complex. Or can I form a query separately then place it into where condition as instance variable.

What is the best approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add `where` statements incrementally when each parameter is present:

```
@xyz = Seeker.scoped
@xyz = @xyz.where(id: params[:id]) if params[:id].present?
@xyz = @zyx.where(mobile_number: params[:mobile_number]) if params[:mobile_number].present?
```

A cleaner approach could be to move that logic to some scope or class method in the Seeker model maybe.

Comment: by this way, I think I will not have much control while writing the query fro DB. Like join/OR condition/in function etc...Am i right?

Comment: I can't see "join"s or "or" queries on your example. But ActiveRecord has, indeed, method for "join" and "or" queries https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#or-conditions https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Answer (score 0):

Hi `I am new to Rails`

If you are using searching for small project, small database, you can use Ruby's [scope](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope) , and take a look at arieljuod's answer. But if you want to make your searching feature is faster, deeper, ... you can find some gems:

- [Sunspot](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot)
- [Searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick)
- [Searchlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic)
- [Ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack)

And there are many other amazing ways with Ruby on Rails.

Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find record based on each parameter are coming and have value that best way to use this is

```
params = {id: nil, mobile_number: "98XXXXXX12" }
Seeker.where(params.compact)
```

**compact** will remove **nil** value from params and directly find with Existing parameter.

**NOTE:** It will remove only **nil** value not **" "** blank String

Comment: but what if id value is present in request URL? will it work?